# Search 'in:inbox is:read' does not work?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I want to move first on read messages in my inbox then go to my unread messages.
I tried to use: `in:inbox is:read` but is give me wrong results.
I also tried this way `in:inbox {NOT is:unread}` But I got the same result.

I get all the read messages and few unread messages, 
I tried to figure out why this happened and find out that  all unread threads includes more than one messages (that say - it include one messages that is read). 
Anyway, I want to see only read messages in this section.

I am new in this system, then if not clear please let me know.

Comment: I tried it now. Now it works well. But I prefer to work in converstion view on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.
In order to do it - you need to search

```
(NOT is:unread) in:inbox
```

This solve the problem while if is one messages that is unread in thread, the thread not will be in the result.

Thanks to @mhoran_psprep on his help

Answer (score 2):

It works as designed.  It is showing you all conversations that have one or more read messages. If you want to only see the messages that have been read then you will have to disable conversations.

Under conversation view google would not know how to address conversations that were mixed, so they made a design decision.

For example if you asked for `in:inbox is:read`

- if all the messages in a conversation have been read, then show the conversation.
- if no messages in the conversation have been read, then hide the conversation.
- if some of the messages have been read,  show the conversation or don't show the conversation.

Sometimes the user would want to show them, sometimes not.  They went with if any message in the conversation meets the criteria then the conversation meets the criteria.

Comment: Thanks. This is any workaround that you know?

Comment: The only workaround that I know is to turn off conversation view.

Comment: I find the work-around and post it as answer. Please see if you have any cooment